# Protractor expect not exist in page

Tags: xpath, protractor, e2e-testing

I have html page like this:

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td>title</td>
        <td>desc</td>
        <td>status</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><label>lorem1</label></td>
        <td><label>desc1 lorem</label></td>
        <td><label>active</label></td>
        <td><a href="http://example.com/post/1/delete"> Delete </a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label>lorem2</label></td>
        <td><label>desc2 lorem</label></td>
        <td><label>active</label></td>
        <td><a href="http://example.com/post/2/delete"> Delete </a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label>lorem3</label></td>
        <td><label>desc3 lorem</label></td>
        <td><label>deactive</label></td>
        <td><a href="http://example.com/post/3/delete"> Delete </a></td>
    </tr>   
</tbody>
</table>
```

Now I delete record `lorem2` from above list (with click on delete link) and after that I want to check `lorem2` that deleted **shouldn't** exist or contain in page.

I write this code but it's not correct:

```
expect(element(by.css("table")).getText()).not.toBe('lorem2');
```

Comment: You're using CSS selector. Why XPath tag was added?\

Comment: I think perhaps this question can solved with Xpath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will delete the `lorem2` by a locator may be `xpath`

below for deleting

```
//tr/td//label[contains(text(),"lorem2")]/following::td/a
```

below for checking if exist after deletion

```
//tr/td//label[contains(text(),"lorem2")]
```

you should parameterize xpath `(i.e)` the text `Lorem2` for other text.

```
expect(element(by.xpath('//tr/td//label[contains(text(),"lorem2")]
')).isPresent()).toBe(false);
```